# Flywheel Working mass parameters of a cross trainer

Tags: training

I have read that better cross trainer devices offer [more flywheel mass](https://www.expertreviews.co.uk/health-and-grooming/1406157/best-cross-trainers-2018-get-fit-with-the-best-elliptical-trainers-from) with 5kg bare minimum.

Now I have found one [offer](https://www.fitnessdigital.de/reebok-one-crosstrainer-gx50-schwarz/p/10006052/?ct=262) which tells me there is a flywheel with 9kg having a working mass of 24 kg.

How is that posible?

Answer (score 1):

By adding friction you can increase the effective resistance to significantly higher amounts. It does not feel exactly the same as a heavier flywheel (it slows much faster, for example) but provides effective resistance from a training perspective.